# How can I load a Python flask app into a gtk webview (Webkit)

Tags: python, webkit, flask, gtk, mathjax

I am currently working on an application that requires math expressions to be rendered (from latex) and needs to have some sort of native gui (even if it just uses gtk, then renders html in webkit).

I did some research and decided an easy way to do this would be to use webkit to load a web page and use a JavaScript library like MathJax to render the math.
Some other reasons why I chosen to do it this way over other solutions are I have had a fair amount of experience developing web apps in python (although a while ago), lack of experience with native guis and the portability it would provide.

For a web app framework I have chosen to use flask as it is one I am most familiar with.

The problem is this application needs to have it's own native GUI through preferably gtk (even if just renders html with webkit) and also preferably shouldn't have a http server that is attached to some socket.

So my question is, instead of running flask's server is there any way to do something like this:

```
import gtk
import webkit

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    window = gtk.Window()

    webview = webkit.WebView()

    webview.load_string(
        app.load_from_uri('/'),
        "text/html",
        "utf-8",
        '/'
    )

    window.add(webview) 
    window.show_all()
```

Where `app.load_from_uri('/')` is just used as an example of a way to load the webpage for a given uri of a Flask app. But as this is just an example, how could `app.load_from_uri('/')` be done in real code?

Also is there anyway to override when the user clicks a link so it does something like this:

```
def link_clicked(uri):
    webview.load_string(
        app.load_from_uri(uri),
        "text/html",
        "utf-8",
        uri
    )
```

Thanks any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ended up finding a solution to this myself (but open to better ones).

The first thing, loading a page, was pretty easy. Flask provides a way to test apps which mainly just sets up all the things for WSGI to be able to process a request. This is just what I needed so I used this like so:

```
from flask import Flask
class WebViewFlask(Flask):
    """
    Adds the ability to load a uri without the
    need of a HTTP server.
    """
    def load_from_uri(self, uri):
        """
        Loads a uri without a running HTTP server.
        """
        with self.test_client() as c:
            response = c.get(uri)
            return response.data, response.mimetype
```

The second part, overriding "when the user clicks a link", is a bit more trickier.

```
import os
import webkit
class FlaskAppView(webkit.WebView):
    """
    Loads pages for flask apps into a WebView.
    """
    def __init__(self, flask_app, *args, **kwargs):
        # Protocol for flask app, by default file:// is used
        # so a protocol is defined here to prevent that.
        self.PROTOCOL = 'flask://' 

        super(webkit.WebView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._flask_app = flask_app

        # Register new navigation handler.
        self.connect(
            "navigation-policy-decision-requested",
            self._nav_request
        )

        # For navigation handler.
        self.prev_uri = None

        # Redefine open like this as when using super
        # an error like this occurs:
        #   AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'open'
        self._open = self.open
        self.open = self.open_

    def _nav_request(self, view, frame, net_req, nav_act, pol_dec):
        """
        WebView navigation handler for Flask apps.
        """
        # Get the uri
        uri = net_req.get_uri()

        # In order for flask apps to use relative links
        # the protocol is removed and it is made into an absolute
        # path.
        if uri.startswith(self.PROTOCOL):
            # In this case it is not relative but
            # it needs to have it's protocol removed
            uri = uri[len(self.PROTOCOL):]

        elif not self.prev_uri.endswith(uri):
            # It is relative and self.prev_uri needs to
            # be appended.
            uri = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(self.prev_uri, uri))

        # This is used to prevent an infinite recursive loop due
        # to view.load_string running this function with the same
        # input.
        if uri == self.prev_uri:
            return False

        self.prev_uri = uri

        # Create response from Flask app.
        response = app.load_from_uri(uri) + ('utf-8', uri)

        # Load response.
        view.load_string(*response)

        # Return False to prevent additional
        # handlers from running.
        return False

    def open_(self, uri):
        """
        Prepends protocol to uri for webkit.WebView.open.
        """
        self._open(self.PROTOCOL + uri)
```

Basically a new navigation event handler is registered with some code to allow for successful recursion and support for relative paths.

Anyway, with that code above by just replacing `Flask` with `WebViewFlask` and `WebView` with `FlaskAppView` everything pretty much just works.

And the result:
[image: result]

Which is a flask app being loaded in a webkit.WebView without any sort of server. The best thing about it is by just switching `app` back to an instance of `Flask` instead of `WebViewFlask` It's a plain webapp again.